# Gitlab CI - Use docker image offline

Tags: image, docker, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to setup a CI solution based on GitLab.

The problem is that my servers are not connected to the internet. I connect them to update then they resume their normal IP address. I want to use GitLab CI and Docker and I want to know how to prepare a docker image (with php, mysql) that is available all the time and not an image downloaded during the tests.

Best regards

Sulian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run your CI builds once with internet enabled and then have them re-use the existing docker images that were pulled during the first run by adding
`pull_policy = "if-not-present"` to the `runners.docker` section of your `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` file. So like:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "Runner name"
  url = ...
  ...
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    image = ...
    pull_policy = "if-not-present"
    ...
```